# Remove few lines from file by means of powershell

Tags: powershell

If I want to remove from document lines with some string key ("foo" for example) I use this:

```
$content = Get-Content 'C:/fake.txt' | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'foo'}
$content | Out-File 'C:/fake.txt'
```

But now I have file with this scheme:

```
...
<data name="BLABLA" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>some data here</value>
</data>
...
<data name="BLABLA22" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>some data</value>
   <comment>some comment</comment>
</data>
```

And I need to remove for key "BLABLA" this three lines

```
<data name="BLABLA" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>some data here</value>
</data>
```

And for key "BLABLA2" this four lines

```
<data name="BLABLA22" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>some data</value>
   <comment>some comment</comment>
</data>
```

How can I do this by means of powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to delete the complete node, then the following should get you there.

```
# load the file into xml
[xml]$dom = gc file.xml

# find the node
$nod = $dom.SelectSingleNode("/root/data[@name='BLABLA']")

# remove the node from the parent
$nod.ParentNode.RemoveChild($nod)

# save the xml
$dom.save("file.xml")
```

I've assumed your data looks a bit like this:

```
<root>
    <data name="BLABLA" xml:space="preserve">
       <value>some data here</value>
    </data>
    <data name="BLABLA22" xml:space="preserve">
       <value>some data</value>
       <comment>some comment</comment>
    </data>
</root>
```